# How to fix gems that stopped working after installing RVM on Mac OS 10.7.5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm, compass-sass, susy-compass

In order to get Rails running correctly on my mac I used this site: http://railsinstaller.org/mac

*Which worked great!* - RVM is installed and the latest version of Ruby.  Unfortunately, I used to use a gem called compass and now it crashes after the new install of RVM.

Is there a way I can just uninstall the old ruby gems I had on Ruby 1.8.7 and reinstall them using the new version of Ruby 1.9.3 I have installed?

when I type gem uninstall compass it says I don't have it installed.  How do I run the gem command from the old version of Ruby? (I'll have to do this for compass and susy and the like)

In fact - can I get a list of all previously installed gems and uninstall all of them?

Comment: I cannot switch to the old ruby through RVM - it says I don't have it installed (which makes sense because it was there BEFORE rvm...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `rvm use system` to change back to the system RVM and gems to uninstall things and list them (`gem list`).

After listing them, you can go install them in the 1.9.3 environment (via normal `gem install`, perhaps with a long list of the gems from the system set)